# Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden) on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Good morning, I'm having serious issues when using Heroku. I was given an application that supposedly was working correctly but at some point it stopped sending emails (which are handled by using sidekiq workers). The application works ok locally but on production it's crashing whenever we try to send emails (or even queue a worker).

I got a couple stacktraces in the logs

The first one is most relevant since I see it most of the times.

First:

```
2014-04-09T19:25:16.043768+00:00 app[web.1]: "Scaling sidekiq to 1"
2014-04-09T19:25:16.188542+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/excon-0.25.1/lib/excon/connection.rb:353:in `response'
2014-04-09T19:25:16.188542+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/excon-0.25.1/lib/excon/connection.rb:247:in `request'
2014-04-09T19:25:16.188542+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/excon-0.25.1/lib/excon/middlewares/expects.rb:6:in `response_call'
2014-04-09T19:25:16.188542+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.13/lib/heroku/api.rb:76:in `request'
2014-04-09T19:25:16.188542+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/autoscaler-0.2.1/lib/autoscaler/heroku_scaler.rb:38:in `workers='
2014-04-09T19:25:16.188542+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.13/lib/heroku/api/processes.rb:36:in `post_ps_scale'
2014-04-09T19:25:16.188312+00:00 app[web.1]: Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)
2014-04-09T19:25:16.188542+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/autoscaler-0.2.1/lib/autoscaler/sidekiq.rb:17:in `call'
2014-04-09T19:25:16.188542+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.10.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:114:in `call'
2014-04-09T19:25:16.188542+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.10.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:114:in `invoke'
2014-04-09T19:25:16.188921+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.10.1/lib/sidekiq/worker.rb:68:in `client_push'
2014-04-09T19:25:16.188921+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.10.1/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:113:in `process_single'
2014-04-09T19:25:16.188921+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.10.1/lib/sidekiq/extensions/generic_proxy.rb:17:in `method_missing'
2014-04-09T19:25:16.188921+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:91:in `each'
2014-04-09T19:25:16.188921+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.10.1/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:41:in `push'
```

Then:

```
2014-04-09T20:48:39.399640+00:00 app[web.2]: "Scaling sidekiq to 1"
2014-04-09T20:48:39.400727+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/excon-0.25.1/lib/excon/response.rb:36:in `parse'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.400727+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/excon-0.25.1/lib/excon/connection.rb:350:in `response'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.400727+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/excon-0.25.1/lib/excon/connection.rb:247:in `request'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.400727+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.13/lib/heroku/api/processes.rb:36:in `post_ps_scale'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.400727+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/autoscaler-0.2.1/lib/autoscaler/heroku_scaler.rb:38:in `workers='
2014-04-09T20:48:39.400943+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.10.1/lib/sidekiq/worker.rb:68:in `client_push'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.400727+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/autoscaler-0.2.1/lib/autoscaler/sidekiq.rb:17:in `call'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.400727+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.10.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:111:in `block in invoke'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.400943+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.10.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:114:in `call'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.400943+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.10.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:114:in `invoke'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.400943+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.10.1/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:113:in `process_single'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.400943+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.10.1/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:41:in `push'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.400943+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-2.10.1/lib/sidekiq/extensions/generic_proxy.rb:17:in `method_missing'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.400943+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/app/models/notification/bid_created.rb:21:in `deliver_email'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.400943+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/app/models/notification/base.rb:39:in `deliver_email_or_queue_digest'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.401134+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:417:in `_run__2996144092637045089__create__484298484390863538__callbacks'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.401134+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.401134+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_create_callbacks'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.401134+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.400943+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:91:in `each'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.401134+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:91:in `method_missing'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.401134+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/app/models/notification/base.rb:25:in `block in deliver_notifications_according_to_preferences'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.401134+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/app/models/notification/base.rb:24:in `map'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.401134+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/app/models/notification/base.rb:24:in `deliver_notifications_according_to_preferences'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.401134+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/app/models/notification/base.rb:14:in `deliver'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.401684+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:268:in `create'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.401684+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:348:in `create_or_update'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.401684+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `block in create_or_update'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.401684+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__2996144092637045089__save__484298484390863538__callbacks'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.401134+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/app/models/bid.rb:59:in `notify_property_managers_of_creation'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.400727+00:00 app[web.2]: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
2014-04-09T20:48:39.400727+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/heroku-api-0.3.13/lib/heroku/api.rb:76:in `request'
2014-04-09T20:48:39.400943+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/app/models/notification/base.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in deliver_notifications_according_to_preferences'
```

Number one suggest and scaling issue, which I have no idea why it may be happening because doing heroku ps outputs correctly sidekiq workers to be 1.
The other one is not clear to me, I debugged the app and is not within my code. Again seems to be related to heroku internal libs. I don't know what to try next and any kind of suggestion would be greatly appreaciated.

EDIT: We fixed temporarily the issue by removing the autoscaler gem and configure Sidekiq manually as recommended at http://manuelvanrijn.nl/blog/2012/11/13/sidekiq-on-heroku-with-redistogo-nano/, However I would really like to keep autoscaler to reduce resource usage. How can I double check if my API_KEY and APP env variables have permission to create new workers? Did a change broke the autoscaler gem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you prove your code is flawless and that "heroku internal libs" are buggy?

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited my response, we were able to resolve the issue momentarily by not using the autoscaler gem. I double checked that configuration for that gem is correctly (HEROKU_APP and HEROKU_API_KEY) but is still failing to scale the workers. How can I check that my app allows to scale through the API? Maybe an internal change broke the gem?